# How to access list from inside a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to delete an event using $http.delete (that's works) and remove this event (using splice) from my vm.events list.

How do I access my vm.events (event list) from the inside of my showEventModal function? My delete button is in a modal.

In the code below, I get `error: vm.events is undefined` with `var index = vm.events.indexOf(event);` and `vm.events.splice(index, 1);` because I don't have access to vm.events inside my showEventModal function:

```
/* 
******************************************
****  Show Event Modal
******************************************
*/
function showEventModal(action, event) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalEventContent.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.action = action;
      vm.event = event;

      vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            vm.event[field] = !vm.event[field];
        };


      vm.eventDeleted = function(event) {

          $http.delete('/api/events/' + event.eventid).success(function(eventsuccess){

          var index = vm.events.indexOf(event);
          vm.events.splice(index, 1);
          }).error(function(err){
          /* do something with errors */
          });

          $modal.close();
      };                 

      vm.eventSaved = function(event) { 


           $http.put('/api/events/' + event.eventid, vm.event).success(function(eventsuccess){
           }).error(function(err){
           /* do something with errors */
           });

           $modal.close();

      };


    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}
```

**update - Added a plunker link**

I've add this code to my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nXJ0SKzDemrhvgWyfue5). It doesn't execute well (because of bad https) but you can see the code above in demo.js

**update - Trying to passe the vm.events scope to my function**

but I get the error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`

I've add `vm.events` in `showEventModal('Edited', event, vm.events);` 
in `function showEventModal(action, event, events)`
in `vm.eventDeleted = function(event, events) {`
and I added `vm.events = events;`

```
/* 
******************************************
****  Show Event Modal
******************************************
*/
function showEventModal(action, event, events) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalEventContent.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.action = action;
      vm.event = event;

      vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            vm.event[field] = !vm.event[field];
        };


      vm.eventDeleted = function(event, events) {

          $http.delete('/api/events/' + event.eventid).success(function(eventsuccess){

          vm.events = events;

          var index = vm.events.indexOf(event);
          vm.events.splice(index, 1);
          }).error(function(err){
          /* do something with errors */
          });

          $modal.close();
      };                 

      vm.eventSaved = function(event) { 


           $http.put('/api/events/' + event.eventid, vm.event).success(function(eventsuccess){
           }).error(function(err){
           /* do something with errors */
           });

           $modal.close();

      };


    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}


vm.eventClicked = function(event) {

     $http.get('/api/events/' + event.eventid).success(function(eventsuccess){

     showEventModal('Edited', event, vm.events);

     }).error(function(err){
   /* do something with errors */
});
  //console.log("logs");
};
```

Comment: This is a flaw with using `controllerAs: 'vm'` for every controller.  You have **two** controllers which are both named `vm`, so the inner controller *hides* access to the parent with the same name.  I advocate using `controllerAs`, but I don't advocate using `vm` as the same name for every controller.  use a unique name for each controller, and you should have an easier time accessing nested properties, and your template logic will feel cleaner as well.

Comment: That's what you do when you're not sure what you're doing :) That's me right now. Just to try, I've changed `controllerAs: 'vm'` from `vm` to `vm2`, plus all references to vm (changed to vm2) in my showEventModal function, but now my modal shows up empty. Again, not sure what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a reference to events in your showEventModal function.

So I think you just need to change instances of:

```
         showEventModal('Edited', event);
```

to:

```
         showEventModal('Edited', event, events);
```

and then change showEventModal to:

```
function showEventModal(action, event, events) {
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modalEventContent.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.action = action;
      vm.event = event;
      vm.events= events;
      ...
```

and then your code that removes the event from the events list should work.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm just not sure about the syntax. He's my plunker. The delete doesn't execute, but all the code is there: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/nXJ0SKzDemrhvgWyfue5)  Would the syntax to pass the events to my function look like this? `function showEventModal(action, event, vm.events) {`

Comment: Yes, it should look something like that. I'm not familiar with the calendar control your using so I can't really comment on exactly where the events are in the API.

Comment: Adding `vm.events` to my function like so : `function showEventModal(action, event, vm.events) {`   gives me this error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`

Comment: You want to pass it in as a parameter where you call it, then probably assign it to vm.events within showEventModal.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate. Got the `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]` this time, see my updates above

Comment: Can you update the Codepen? Also where are modalContent.html and modalEventContent.html? I don't understand how the Codepen works without these, but it seems to.

Comment: The plunker was updated (code above is in demo.js) and the modalEventContent.html is defined in index.html